# Prove $C^n(\mathbb{R})\cong C(\mathbb{R})$ (linear isomorphism)

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that

### $C^n(\mathbb{R})\cong C(\mathbb{R})$,

that is, there exists a bijective linear function from $C^n(\mathbb{R})$ onto  $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enough to show they have the same dimension (here the dimension is a certain infinite cardinal, namely the cardinality of a basis).

Since $C^n\subset C$ it's clear that $\dim(C^n)\le\dim(C)$. For the other inequality:

> > If $f\in C$ there exists $g\in C^1$ with $g'=f$.

Proof: $g(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$.

By induction:

> > If $f\in C$ there exists $g\in C^n$ with $g^{(n)}=f$.

So if we define $T:C^n\to C$ by $Tf=f^{(n)}$ then $T$ is surjective; hence $\dim(C^n)\ge \dim(C)$.

Here we used a basic fact about dimension:

> > If $T:X\to Y$ is linear then $\dim(TX)\le\dim(X)$.

Proof: Say $B$ is  a basis for $X$. Then $T(B)$ spans $TX$, so $T(B)$ contains a basis for  $TX$; hence $\dim(TX)\le\text{card}(T(B))\le\text{card}(B)=\dim(X)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!